# How to resolve error: "undefined" when reading single values from JSON using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript function that outputs all values from a JSON file to a Terminal, but when attempting to print a single value, I get the following error: Line 74 - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'width')

Here is the code:

```
var json = `{
    "columns": [{
            "fname": "John",
            "lname": "Doe",
            "age": "23"
        },
        {
            "fname": "Jane",
            "lname": "Doe",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "fname": "Tom",
            "lname": "Johns",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "fname": "Brian",
            "lname": "Wicks",
            "age": "27"
        },
        {
            "fname": "Tim",
            "lname": "Stone",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "fname": "Fred",
            "lname": "Wilson",
            "age": ""
        },
        {
            "fname": "Jason",
            "lname": "Voorhees",
            "age": "90"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [{
        "data": {
            "width": "2",
            "height": "7",
            "length": "",
            "finalresult": "44",
            "firstresult": "",
            "secondresult": "300.00",
            "thirdresult": "700.40"
        }
    }]
}`;


var obj = JSON.parse(json);


function printValues(obj) {
    for(var k in obj) {
        if(obj[k] instanceof Object) {
            printValues(obj[k]);
        } else {
            console.log(obj[k] + "\n");
        };
    }
};

// Printing all the values from the resulting object
printValues(obj);

//print single value
//console.log(obj["columns"]["rows"]["data"]["width"] + "\n"); 
console.log("Print Indiviual values:");
console.log(obj["rows"]["data"]["width"] + "\n"); //The Error
```

...Could I get some assistance as to what I'm doing wrong? ...Thanks

Comment: `rows` is an array. As such, try `obj["rows"][0]["data"]["width"]`

Comment: Thanks, ...that worked out great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yarin and @codemonkey pointed out—you're trying to access the `data` object as a direct object property of `rows`, e.g. `obj.rows.data` which is wrong and will return `undefined` because `data` is **not** a property of the `rows` object. Instead it's the first (and only) entry in the array of objects that is `rows`.

You need to either change the syntax to:

```
obj.rows[0].data.width
```

Or take the `data` object out of the array and remove the array so that the rows object is structured like this:

```js
const obj = {
  rows: {
    data: {
      width: 1
    }
  }
}

// Then you can use this syntax...
console.log( obj.rows.data.width )

// or even this syntax if you want to...
console.log( obj['rows']['data']['width'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the width is the property of object data that is inside array rows...